# Can Java specify what class loader to use for deserialization?

Tags: java

Can Java specify what class loader to use for deserialization?

It is best to be based on jdk 1.8.

thanks.

Comment: @huy On the contrary, it is extremely clear. 'I don't understand your question' isn't the same thing as 'your question is not clear'.

Comment: Your question is answered in the Javadoc for `ObjectInputStream`.